# Http 403 Forbidden Error on one folder

Tags: http, web, http-status-code-403

I have a website (Hoster: one.com) with different gallerys (one, two, three), like this:

```
www.site.com/galleries/one/pic1.png
www.site.com/galleries/one/pic2.png
www.site.com/galleries/two/pic1.png
www.site.com/galleries/three/pic1.png
...
```

I can refer to any picture of any gallery, EXCEPT for one gallery. I get an 403-Error for any picture in that folder, saying:

```
"You don't have permission to access /galleries/four/pic1.png on this server."
```

I don't understand this, since they are structured exactly the same way. There is no difference between those folders except for the name.

I have an htpaccess-file, where I only specify url-redirections that don't involve this issue.

What can I do? If I have to grant permissions, why are the other folders possible to read? How would I allow permissions?

Thank you in advance!